# Не могу вытащить связанные таблицы

Tags: php, laravel

Мой контроллер

```
$reports = DB::table('orders_user')->get();
$reports_pro = DB::table('order_products')->orderBy('orders_user_id','asc')->get();
```

Модель

```
class orders_user extends Model
{
    public $table = "orders_user"; 
    protected $guarded = []; 


    public function order_products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order_products');
    }
}
```

Шаблон:

```
@foreach ($reports as $item)
    @foreach($item->reports_pro as $ite)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $ite->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $ite->name }}</td>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

У меня есть 2 таблицы. связаны они по айди. Мне нужно вытащить товар с обоих таблиц. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какой фреймворк Вы используете ?

Comment: @madfan41k laravel

Comment: Вы как таблицы с моделями создавали? Через `artisan`?

Comment: @doox911 нет, вручную

Comment: Так вот создайте через, `artisan`.  И следуйте принятым правилам создания моделей и таблиц.

Comment: Алишер, понимаю, что ты начинающий прогер. Почитай лучшие практики кодинга https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices. Там есть советы по именованию классов, переменных, контроллеров и т.д. И почитай документацию по Eloquent ORM, там про связи очень подробно написано

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте в контроллере прописать

```
$users = DB::table('orders_user')->get();

foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
    foreach($user->order_products as $product) {
        echo $product->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$order_products